# Convertir el resultado de una consulta en un JSON

Tags: c#

Estoy realizando una consulta en el motor de base de datos HANA, y me devuelve los siguientes registros:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Requiere convertir estos registros en una estructura JSON de está manera:

```
 {
  "articulos": [
      {
        "ItemCode": 7703907029268,
        "ItemName": "942 MAGGIA SHIRT BEIGE CLARO TM",
        "ItemGrupo": "MAGGIA",
        "Price": 0
      },
      {
        "ItemCode": 7703907090572,
        "ItemName": "2459J BRAS - 2 PANTIES T32/S",
        "ItemGrupo": "CJTO BRASIER TRIO",
        "Price": 36.900
      }
    ]
}
```

Lo estoy tratando de hacer de está manera pero no logro convertir a JSON.

```
string QueryVar = service.configParteConsulta(service.DBServerType, "ReferenciasArticulosShopifyTEST", "/TQueries/Queries/Query");
                        oRsetVariante = cn.eQuery(Convert.ToString(QueryVar));

                        foreach (DataRow oRow1 in oRsetVariante.Rows)
                        {
                            strResultado = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(oRow1, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);
                            Console.Write(strResultado);
                            List<object> variants = new List<object>();
                            Cabecera.variants = variants;
                            dynamic variante = new ExpandoObject();
                            for (int x = 1; x <= oRsetVariante.Rows.Count; x++)
                            {
                                // Adicionar Variante
                                Variant varianteProduct = new Variant();
                                varianteProduct.price = Convert.ToDecimal(oRow1["Price"].ToString());
                                varianteProduct.sku = oRow1["U_RefCorta"].ToString();
                                varianteProduct.option1 = oRow1["U_RefCorta"].ToString() + "_" + oRow1["U_Color"].ToString() + ".jpg";
                                varianteProduct.option2 = oRow1["U_Talla"].ToString();
                                varianteProduct.barcode = oRow1["ItemCode"].ToString();
                                variants.Add(varianteProduct);
                            }
                        }
```

Comment: @TheOligarch podes poner eso como respuesta, estructurada como corresponde?

Answer (score -1):

Te recomiendo crees una clase Articulo con las propiedades correspondientes y que el resultado que estas obteniendo de la consulta lo guardes un en una colección de tipo Articulo luego esta colección la pase como parámetro en `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value:)`, espero que esto te esto te ayude.